# ArcMap Skyline Tool only returns a part of the desired output

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst

I'm aware there are multiple posts on this matter, but those did not provide the help I was looking for.

Background: I have a set of points in a shapefile from which I want to generate a skyline polygon each. I wanted to repeat this for multiple resampled scales of the same DEM (5m, 10m, 30m, 90m) to see how the skyline is affected by using different DEM scales. The DEMs were resampled using GDAL.

The problem: When I ran the six points (one by one for every resolution each), I only get a skyline polygon for 4 out of the 6 points per input DEM. Map: one example of successful output, table: attribute table showing the unsuccessful points.

[image: the observed output of the skyline tool]
[image: The skyline tool attribute table]

Problem analysis:

- All the DEMs and the points share the same CRS & projection.
- The observed problem does not depend on the extracted Z-elevation of the input points. Although there is variation in the exact elevation of the points per DEM-resolution, this is the case for the successful points as well.
- It is not the spatial coverage of the DEM, because when I enlarge the DEM, the same situation remains.
- It is not a legacy issue of using ArcMap (version 10.8.1) because the same is observed in ArcGISPro (version 3.1).

How can I get the skyline polygons from the remaining two points?

You can find the data (One DEM + the points) [here](https://nguno-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/sven-arne_quist_ngu_no/EroEahzV0uZGs9wAMQk62-UBqE6Jj5h3OA1Pekg900mDcw?e=aoc1A2)

Comment: Please provide links to the “ multiple posts on this matter” that you are aware of. That helps us clean up any duplicates and saves us having to search for them before deciding whether and how to help.

Comment: Your shapefile that you provide in your link appears to be corrupted, so cannot test. Rasters are OK.

Comment: Hi, the data is updated in the folder under the link.